# How do I get typescript to stop complaining about static members on a function?

Tags: typescript

my example pretty much explains the issue.

but basically, I'm trying to understand how to write valid typescript when adding static members to a function in the code below

```
export const ZoomPanelControl = (props) => undefined;
ZoomPanelControl.Item = (props) => undefined;
```

[link for fiddle](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20const%20ZoomPanelControl%20%3D%20(props)%20%3D%3E%20undefined%3B%0D%0AZoomPanelControl.Item%20%3D%20(props)%20%3D%3E%20undefined%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to add a property to a function is to use `Object.assign()` to create the function-with-property in a single statement:

```
export const ZoomPanelControl = Object.assign(
    (props) => undefined,
    { Item: (props) => undefined }
);
```

This produces an object of type `((props: any) => any) & { Item: (props: any) => any; }`, which is what you want:

```
ZoomPanelControl(123); // okay
ZoomPanelControl.Item(456); // okay
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you need "a gap" between defining the function and assigning the properties, you can use a type assertion:

```
type Example = {
    (props: any): any;
    [key: string]: (props: any) => any;
}

const ZoomPanelControl = <Example>((props) => undefined);

//...

ZoomPanelControl.Item = (props) => undefined;
```

You could place the type within the type assertion, but that's one heck of a line of code to read, which is why I pulled it out into the `Example` type instead.

The compiler still makes a general check of `((props) => undefined)` against the the signature of the `Example` type - so there is type safety in there as opposed to one common alternative:

```
const ZoomPanelControl: Example = <any>((props) => undefined);
```

And you can limit it to known members, if you don't want to allow "any string as a key"...

```
type Example = {
    (props: any): any;
    Item: (props: any) => any;
}
```

If you are setting this up in one hit, [jcalz answer has the benefit of type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399117/75525) (it effectively gives you the type in my last code block, but for free).